# Reliable way to check if a DRAC card is installed in Linux environment?

Tags: linux, debian, dell, drac

I have some Dell servers which I'm not sure if there are any DRAC cards installed (shame on me), and I'm trying to find a way to check it.

Up to now, `lspci` and `omreport` reports nothing. `dmesg | grep DRAC` is unreliable since it gets rotated. `racadm` should work but I've no way to get it installed on a Debian box.

Any more ideas? Thanks.

Comment: I get a working copy of `racadm` from https://subtrac.sara.nl/oss/omsa_2_deb, and it works.

(I'm a regular user of `omreport`/`omconfig`, but missed the `racadm` part of sara-omsa. Silly me.)

Still wondering about the `lspci` issue, though.

Answer (score 9):

"ipmitool sdr elist mcloc" is probably what you're looking for; it even works with the newer iDRAC6es, which are integrated with the mainboard and thus don't show up in the FRU list:

```
$ sudo ipmitool sdr elist mcloc
BMC              | 00h | ok  |  7.1 | Dynamic MC @ 20h
DRAC 5           | 00h | ok  | 11.1 | Dynamic MC @ 26h

$ bash-3.00$ sudo ipmitool sdr elist mcloc
iDRAC6           | 00h | ok  |  7.1 | Dynamic MC @ 20h
```

Comment: This is a perfectly direct method, and worked with both DRAC and iDRAC. Thanks for the tip, saving this one!

Answer (score 3):

[This post](http://lists.us.dell.com/pipermail/firmware-tools-devel/2009-April/000438.html) indicates that `lspci` should be able to see the card:

```
04:04.0 Class ff00: Dell Remote Access Card 4
04:04.1 Class ff00: Dell Remote Access Card 4 Daughter Card Virtual UART
04:04.2 Class ff00: Dell Remote Access Card 4 Daughter Card SMIC
```

Comment: My cards are all DRAC 5. Maybe it's a DRAC 5 issue?

Answer (score 2):

what about listing usb devices?

you should find at least virtual kbd / mouse, and possibly pendrive / cd.

```
somehost0:~# lsusb -v|less
Bus 001 Device 036: ID 413c:0000 Dell Computer Corp.
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               1.10
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0
  bDeviceProtocol         0
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x413c Dell Computer Corp.
  idProduct          0x0000
  bcdDevice            0.00
  iManufacturer           1 Dell
  iProduct                2 DRAC5
  ....
```

it seems it can be narrowed down to parsing result of:

```
lsusb -v -d 413c:0000
```

Comment: `lsusb` requires root privileges to get the DRAC info. A simple `grep` against `/proc/bus/usb/devices` would be cheaper, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

not a solution, but if it's debian the boot messages are stored in /var/log/dmesg* which is not rotated. Still you have to know what you're looking for in terms of name; perhaps it shows up on lspci with an 'unknown' name?

Comment: Good catch. /var/log/dmesg is NOT rotated. I was wrong.

Comment: /var/log/dmesg CAN be rotated if it's specified in /etc/logrotate.d/syslog (or one of the other files in /etc/logrotate.d)

Answer (score 0):

As [lorenzog noted](https://serverfault.com/questions/93332/reliable-way-to-check-if-a-drac-card-is-installed-in-linux-environment/93340#93340), /var/log/dmesg is not rotated as I thought, so let's grep it:

```
$ grep -i 'dell\|drac' /var/log/dmesg
ACPI: RSDP (v002 DELL                                  ) @ 0x00000000000f2a00
ACPI: XSDT (v001 DELL   PE_SC3   0x00000001 DELL 0x00000001) @ 0x00000000000f2a80
ACPI: FADT (v003 DELL   PE_SC3   0x00000001 DELL 0x00000001) @ 0x00000000000f2b88
ACPI: MADT (v001 DELL   PE_SC3   0x00000001 DELL 0x00000001) @ 0x00000000000f2c7c
ACPI: SPCR (v001 DELL   PE_SC3   0x00000001 DELL 0x00000001) @ 0x00000000000f2d5d
ACPI: HPET (v001 DELL   PE_SC3   0x00000001 DELL 0x00000001) @ 0x00000000000f2dad
ACPI: MCFG (v001 DELL   PE_SC3   0x00000001 DELL 0x00000001) @ 0x00000000000f2de5
ACPI: DSDT (v001 DELL   PE_SC3   0x00000001 MSFT 0x0100000e) @ 0x0000000000000000
input: Dell DRAC5 as /class/input/input0
input: USB HID v1.10 Keyboard [Dell DRAC5] on usb-0000:00:1d.7-1.1
input: Dell DRAC5 as /class/input/input1
input: USB HID v1.10 Mouse [Dell DRAC5] on usb-0000:00:1d.7-1.1
  Vendor: Dell      Model: Virtual  CDROM    Rev: 123
  Vendor: Dell<7>usb-storage: device scan complete
```

There are two USB devices attributed to DRAC. However, I still have no way to get it listed under `lspci`. DRAC should be connected to a PCI bus, right?

Comment: I'd be cautious of parsing `/var/log/dmesg`. It should work, but it's a static file created at boot and not necessarily indicative of the running state. Likewise the output from `dmesg` can sometimes be filled past it's buffer. Much safer to use procfs or sysfs where possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a DRAC installed, does it supercede the Baseboard Mananagment Controller's IPMI interface?  If so, you can query through IPMI to see what the settings are.

Answer (score 0):

There is an easier way to check the iDRAC version:

```
server# omreport chassis info |grep DRAC
iDRAC6 Version                           : 1.50
```